# Is there a way to create a module that can be consumed by both ESM and CJS applications?

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs, rollupjs, mjs

I have a backend CJS application & a frontend ESM application. And a node module I have created in ESM.
The node module works fine for my ESM application because they are both using ESM `import` syntax.
Trying to consume it in the CJS application obviously throws errors as it cannot read the ESM `import` syntax.

I've tried using `Rollup.js` to convert the `ESM` code into `CJS` and using `conditional exports` in my `package.json` file but this does not work.

Comment: Important question: why? Node [can import either](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_interoperability_with_commonjs) as long as your project, and your dependency projects, clearly indicate which flavour of ES they use (i.e. if your code uses ESM, you _need_ to specify `type: "module"` in your `package.json`)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans 
Hi Mike.
And because I have a file like dataUtils that is used in my frontend applications and also used in my backend api applications.
So making it into an npm package for this file makes sense.
So I need it to be consumed in CJS when my backend api is consuming it and in ES6 when my frontend apps are using it.

Comment: No, you don't. You can just write ES6 for both, because Node can import and run ES6 perfectly fine, _even in projects that themselves are CJS_: just set the right values in `package.json` if you're code uses ES modules instead of the legacy commonjs require approach.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is a library like:

my-library.js

```js
// No require on top. They will be local to their use.
const myLibrary = ...

// export default instead of module.exports
export default myLibrary
```

The library must first have its extension rename to .mjs ("my-library.js" = "my-library.msj")

Then,

in CJS (Node.js) =>

Dynamic import:

```js
const {default: myUtilityLib } = await import("./my-library.mjs");
```

In ESM (Browser) =>

Standard import as usual:

```js
import myUtilityLib from "./my-library.mjs"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify on the `package.json` which file to look into depending on the environment. Its also important to know that CommonJS uses `require` syntax for module imports. The esbuild [main-fields](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#main-fields) documentation covers this quite nicely.

The general approach is that you'll build 2 files, one on `CommonJS` format to be used for `main` field, the other is in `Ecmascript` format for the `module` field.

```
// package.json
{
  ...
  "main": "<name of your cjs file>",
  "module": "<name of your esm file>",
  ...
}
```